# The build.gradle files conflict and create two totally same application on the device

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have two build.gradle (**:app**, **:omimhikingbook**) in my application. **:app** is for build application and **omimhikingbook** is for build library, but after click **Run 'app'** button in Android Studio. Then will create two same totally same application on the device.

The image of [the result on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igpxx.png)

I guess it could be the **buildTypes** in two files have some conflict.
But I not really sure the reason and how to adjust the gradle config to fix the problems.

Here is the code of **(:app)** build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

repositories {
    ...
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.hikingbook.hikingbook'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

    }

    splits.abi {
        boolean enabled = project.hasProperty('splitApk');
        println ("Create separate apks: " + enabled)
        enable enabled
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        universalApk true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: false, analyticsEnabled: false, performanceLogcatEnabled: false]
            buildConfigField 'String', 'OFFICIAL_WEBSITE', '\"https://hikingbook.net\"'
        }
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsEnabled: true, analyticsEnabled: true, performanceLogcatEnabled: true]
            buildConfigField 'String', 'OFFICIAL_WEBSITE', '\"https://hikingbook.net\"'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'txt', 'bin', 'html', 'png', 'json', 'mwm', 'ttf', 'sdf', 'ui', 'config', 'csv', 'spv'
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!.svn:!.git:!.DS_Store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    ...

    // Omim-Hikingbook, this line will implementation (:omimhikingbook) as library
    implementation project(path: ':omimhikingbook') 

    ...

}
```

and the code of **(:omimhikingbook)** build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

...

project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 30, 'x86': 40, 'arm64-v8a': 50, 'x86_64' : 60]
project.ext.appId = 'com.hikingbook.hikingbook'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ...

        multiDexEnabled true
        multiDexKeepFile file('../multidex-config.txt')

        externalNativeBuild {
            ...
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        ...
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        web {
            dimension "default"
            versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + '-Web'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'SUPPORT_MAIL', '"googleplay@maps.me"'
            android.sourceSets.web.assets.srcDirs = ['../flavors/mwm-ttf-assets']
        }
    }

    splits.abi {
        boolean enabled = project.hasProperty('splitApk');
        println ("Create separate apks: " + enabled)
        enable enabled
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        universalApk true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix '-debug'
            jniDebuggable true           // Enable jni debug build
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.mapswithme
            android.sourceSets.debug.setRoot('../flavors/debug')
            ndk {
                abiFilters "x86", "arm64-v8a"
            }
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.mapswithme
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile('../proguard-mwm.txt')
            ndk {
                abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            ...
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'txt', 'bin', 'html', 'png', 'json', 'mwm', 'ttf', 'sdf', 'ui', 'config', 'csv', 'spv'
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!.svn:!.git:!.DS_Store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }

    // Enables new Java features in KitKat+ but needs Java 1.7 installed
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        ...
    }
}

...
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    ...
}
```

If there have any information miss or suggestion to fix the problem. Please let me know.

Thanks a lot~~~

**-- Update --**

The AndroidManifest of **(:omimhikingbook)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.hikingbook.omimhikingbook.maps"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MwmApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/MwmTheme"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.hikingbook.omimhikingbook.maps.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <!-- standard "geo" scheme -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="geo"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="ge0"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="ge0.me"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="ge0.me"
                    android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="maps.google.com"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="maps.google.com"
                    android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="lead"
                    android:scheme="mapsme"/>
                <data
                    android:host="lead"
                    android:scheme="mapswithme"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="dlink.maps.me"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                    android:host="dlink.mapsme.devmail.ru"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:scheme="mapsme"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- API CALL -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mapswithme.maps.api.request"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mapswithme.maps.pro.action.SHOW_ON_MAP"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mapswithme.maps.pro.action.BUILD_ROUTE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kmz"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.kmz"
                    android:scheme="file"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="*/*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.kml"
                    android:scheme="file"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.hikingbook.omimhikingbook.maps.DownloadResourcesLegacyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>

        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.hikingbook.omimhikingbook.maps.DownloadResourcesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:targetActivity="com.hikingbook.omimhikingbook.maps.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity
            android:name="com.hikingbook.omimhikingbook.maps.MwmActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="${applicationId}"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

</manifest>
```

**-- Conclution --**

Thanks for **Saurabh Thorat** provide the answer. The actually reason is the application and library both have this code in **AndroidManifest**

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

So just remove the code then it will get correct result.
The image of [the currect result on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP9R1.png)

Comment: Can you post `AndroidManifest.xml` of your `omimhikingbook`?

Comment: Hi, @SaurabhThorat. Sure, I have updated the question.

Comment: The problem may be affected by the AndroidManifest of omimhikingbook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from `AndroidManifest.xml` of `omimhikingbook`:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This is awesome!!! I didn't expect it was caused by this reason. Thank you a lot~~~